# Autoprefixer in file watcher JetBrains IDEs

Tags: css, node.js, less, jetbrains-ide, autoprefixer

I made it earlier, but not remember, how to custom File watcher for LESS -> CSS with autoprefixer.
It was like

```
--no-color $FileName$ --autoprefix="last 5 versions"
```

but now it isn't working.

[my File Watcher settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQ3zu.png)
**I won't use gulp** or etc. I have *Node.js* + *npm* and *Less / Sass support* and *autoprefixer plugins* and *less-plugin-autoprefix*
I used `npm install -g less-plugin-autoprefix` from this https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix

Comment: what doesn't work namely?does the same command work in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me (Lessc 2.7.2, less-plugin-autoprefix 1.5.1)

[image]

```
.cls {
    display: flex;
}
```

is transpiled into

```
.cls {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```